# Does Wakanda have Nuclear Weapons? (or any weapons of mass destruction with similar capabilities?)

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, black-panther-2018

Hopefully the title says it all. If not specifically nuclear weapons, then maybe some kind of Vibranium-Nuke was mentioned?

Comment: Well, in the movies I don't think so.. But in the Black Panther comics series by Chris Priest, there have been an elite team of Panther mech-suits (near indestructible Doomsday machines) and the N'Yami class battle cruisers which are equipped with nuclear weaponry. If this is what you're looking for, I could elaborate it as an answer.

Comment: @Shreedhar Thank you, this is exactly what I'm looking for. Feel free to add it as an answer

Comment: "If not specifically **nuclear** weapons, then maybe some kind of Vibranium-**Nuke**"  is an oxymoron.

Comment: @Lexible Haha, by that statement I meant a weapon made of Vibranium that has similar effects to a nuclear weapon

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**As the OP is alright with the answers from the comic books as well, I'm posting this.**

---

Although the movie **Black Panther (2018)** did not present any hints if (or not) the Wakandan nation possesses any WMDs (Weapons of Mass destruction, nuclear or otherwise), in the three-volume series by Christopher Priest, there have been at least two WMDs presented.

Firstly, the **N'Yami class Battle Cruise ships**. Named in honor of T'Challa's mother (and King T'Chaka's first wife), these battle ships are enormous and have WMDs capable of destroying entire cities.

[image]
 <sub>***Black Panther vol 3. Issue 27***</sub>

---

The second set of machinery that the Wakandans possess capable of inflicting great damage are the **Panther mech suits** (or well-known as the **Giant Panther Prowlers**).

[image]
 <sub>***Black Panther vol 3. Issue 10***</sub>

The prowlers were first introduced in Black Panther Vol. 3 Issue 10 through 12. ***Achebe*** (a resident of an African country of Ghudaza) was driven insane after his wife was killed and he was left for dead. At one time, he gained access to the Gaint Prowler robots and sent them to attack Wakanda. His plan was however foiled in time by T'Challa.

These Prowlers are near-indestructible machines and were sometimes also referred to as Doomsday bots.

---

### So, in conclusion, Wakanda does have WMDs. But I don't recall the Black Panther actually using them (to destroy cities etc.).